Looking for a specific "Gummi bears" episode
I am looking for a particular episode of "Disney's Adventures of the Gummi Bears" in which there is a scene where Toadie leads the ogre troops and they all sing like in the US army. The Bulgarian version of the song sounds literally like this:

Toadie: Who is the best team?
Army: Ogre! Ogres!
Toadie: Who smells like crushed ferret?
Army: Ogres! Ogres!


Seems like Ogre for a Day (Season 5, episode 5). From Wikia:

Zummi discovers a transformation spell that does not work on Gummi Bears, but does for Cavin, who takes the guise of an ogre and infiltrates the ogre ranks of Castle Drekmore to uncover Duke Igthorn's latest plot. But his new form makes communicating his good intentions to the right people a little difficult. 

During the episode the ogres chant:

Toadwart: [singing to the tune of "Sound Off"] Who's a cut above the rest?
Ogres: [spoken] Ogres! Ogres!
Toadwart: Who smells like a vulture's nest?
Ogres: Ogres! Ogres! 

You can see the scene here at 10:23:



